# Does pthread_once_t variable need a mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

we use One-Time initialization for pthreads like this:

```
/* define a statically initialized pthread_once_t variable */
pthread_once_t once_var = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

/* we call pthread_once function in threads */
int pthread_once(pthread_once_t *once_control, void (*init)(void));
```

when more than one thread is going to change the state of `pthread_once_t` variable, do we need a mutex for protecting it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need a mutex for this. The `pthread_once` call ([link here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_once.html)) is guaranteed to be executed once and once only, even if multiple threads try it at the same time.

It's the `once_var` that's protecting the call from being executed more than once. It will work as expected, provided that you:

- initialise the `once_var` to `PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT`; and
- ensure that `once_var` is not of automatic storage duration (eg, on the stack); and
- have all threads use the same `once_var` variable.

Comment: Why do you need to ensure that `once_var` is not automatic? It should work just fine as long as it remains in scope for the entire duration of possible use.

Comment: @R: Because that's what the man page says :-) It's undefined behaviour if the variable is automatic. It _may_ work, UB sometimes does, but that doesn't make it a wise decision to depend on it, any more than the UB in the ISO C standard. I suspect it _is_ the possibility of going out of scope that they're worried about but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5):

pthread_once is thread safe. You can think of the pthread_once_t variable as the mutex in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If it did, this whole mechanism would be utterly useless. Whatever you used to ensure that you only initialized that mutex once could just as easily do whatever it is you are using *this* mechanism to do once.